# Can I have xml schema define data type choises

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd

I have a somewhat simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<SearchSettings>
    <ChangeHistory>
        <Changed By="Joe Schmoe" On="2013-07-17">Initial creation of this file.</Changed>
    </ChangeHistory>

    <Logicals>
        <Logical Name="Exact Match"  ShortName="EM" Operator="== {0}" />
        <Logical Name="Contains"     ShortName="Co" Operator="%{0}%" />
        <Logical Name="Starts With"  ShortName="SW" Operator="{0}%" />
        <Logical Name="Ends With"    ShortName="EW" Operator="%{0}" />
        <Logical Name="Between"      ShortName="Be" Operator="gt= {0} AND lt= {0}" />
        <Logical Name="Less Than"    ShortName="LT" Operator="lt {0}" />
        <Logical Name="Greater Than" ShortName="GT" Operator="gt {0}" />
    </Logicals>

    <LogicalGroupings>
        <Group DisplayType="Text"    Allowed="EM|Co|SW|EW" />
        <Group DisplayType="Decimal" Allowed="EM|Be|LT|GT" />
        <Group DisplayType="Integer" Allowed="EM|Be|LT|GT" />
        <Group DisplayType="Date"    Allowed="EM|Be|LT|GT" />
        <Group DisplayType="List"    Allowed="EM" />
    </LogicalGroupings>

    <SearchFields>
        <SearchField DisplayName="Complaint Type"   DisplayType="List"    ColumnName="Complaint.ComplaintTypeID" GetMethod="GetComplaintTypes" ToolTipTitle="" ToolTipContent="" ToolTipKey="" Transform="" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Complaint Number" DisplayType="Text"    ColumnName="Complaint.Number" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Tax Year"         DisplayType="Integer" ColumnName="Complaint.TaxYear" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Category"         DisplayType="List"    ColumnName="Complaint.Category"        GetMethod="GetExistingCategories" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Building Value"   DisplayType="Integer" ColumnName="Complaint.BuildingValue" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Land Value"       DisplayType="Integer" ColumnName="Complaint.LandValue" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Owner Opinion"    DisplayType="Integer" ColumnName="Complaint.OwnerOpinion" />
        <SearchField DisplayName="Notes"            DisplayType="Text"    ColumnName="Complaint.Notes"           AllowedLogicals="Co" />
    </SearchFields>
</SearchSettings>
```

And I want the SearchFields.SearchField.DisplayType to only allow the DisplayType values from the LogicalGroupings list.

Is this possible?  I keep trying to add a foreign key only relationship but then my schema intellisence stops working so I figure I am wrong.

**EDIT**

Here is my existing (working but without what I want yet) .xsd file.  I removed the sections I do not care about to save space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SearchSettings" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="SearchSettings" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="LogicalGroupings">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Group" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="DisplayType" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="Allowed" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="SearchFields">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="SearchField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="DisplayName" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="DisplayType" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="ColumnName" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="GetMethod" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="ToolTipTitle" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="ToolTipContent" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="ToolTipKey" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="Transform" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="AllowedLogicals" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the level of SearchSettings, define an xs:key with selection="LogicalGrouping/Group", field="@DisplayType", and a corresponding xs:keyref with selection="SearchFields/Searchfield", field="@DisplayType".

(If you tried something, it's best to tell us what you tried and how it failed, so we can explain where you went wrong...)

Comment: Hi @Michael, I added the following line:

<xs:key selection="LogicalGrouping/Group" field="@DisplayType" />

Just below the SearchSettings element line, which is now line 4.  Then added to the DisplayType down in the SearchField as follows:

<xs:attribute name="DisplayType" type="xs:string" selection="SearchFields/SearchField" field="@DisplayType" />

But the xs:key at the top is not passing validation.  Selection and field seem to not be valid attributes.  And with that said, the selection attribute in the SearchField fails.  I will look more into this to see what I am missing.

Comment: Need to see exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.